# applescript/automator close and save

Tags: applescript

Can anyone tell me why this script, running on a fileset in automator leaves all my TextMate windows open with the save prompt waiting for my input instead of actually saving and closing the file?

I assumed that the line `close window 1 saving yes` would save and close the file and continue with the next but it seems it doesn't.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    repeat with a from 1 to length of input
        tell application "TextMate"

            activate
            open item a of input

            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "TextMate"
                    tell menu bar 1
                        tell menu bar item "Text"
                            tell menu "Text"
                                tell menu item "Convert"
                                    tell menu "Convert"
                                        click menu item "Tabs to Spaces"
                                    end tell
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell

            close window 1 saving yes

        end tell
    end repeat

    return input
end run
```

[image]

Comment: Although I can't answer the question, I will note that `expand` in a shell script is a practical way to convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: That's awesome Michael ... it's exactly what i've been looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say either TextMate is simply presenting the opportunity to save (or cancel), this is a bug, or this is an incomplete implementation of the command within TextMate. But only TextMate's devs can answer that question.

Commands and their implementations are completely up to the developer and their applications; there are no enforced or encouraged standards given by Apple to go by. The command `close window 1 saving yes` in the Adobe Creative Suite causes the document to be saved and then closed without user intervention, and it is pure coincidence the syntax is the same.

Comment: Guess i'll have to tell it to click the save menu item then and after that the close menu item ... it's a hassle but probably will work. Thanks!